# Domain user profile messed up - how can I recreate it and keep docs/etc?

Tags: windows, user-profile

**SITUATION**

I have a user that we were trying to get Office 365 Pro Plus installed on their computer.  It kept crashing, etc.  I don't want to get into all of the details here on that part...I've spent most of the day trying to remedy it from that perspective.  I finally found that logging in as a different user allowed Office to install and run just fine, but then switching back to the problem user profile immediately causes any Office app to crash and then integratedoffice.exe tries to run in the background to repair Office 365 Pro Plus and never works.  There always seems to be corrupt files and app crashes withing the user's appdata\local\temp folder, even after clearing it out and recreating the Temp\Low properly.  I've tried all kinds of things like Disk Cleanup, sfc /scannow, registry 
cleanups, etc.

---

**So, let's focus on just removing their domain profile from the computer and recreating it...**

*I found this article: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile but it doesn't quite detail out what's involved if the user is a domain profile, even though it starts down that path.*

I figure I can backup the profile folder(s) to a thumbdrive, log in as a domain admin, delete the problematic domain user profile, have them login again to create a new one, and then move the documents/music/pics back.

But is the above the "right" way to do it?  Or is there a better method out there for repairing a corrupted profile and retaining their personal docs/etc?

Comment: Don't forget to delete the associated entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` if you manually delete a profile from the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about only documents, pictures, etc. and not profile or application data or settings then I think the cleanest way is to copy the documents, pictures, etc. to an alternate location, delete the user profile, recreate the user profile and copy the documents, pictures, etc. back to the new profile.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing that will be sufficient enough.  I was hoping for something that would start their profile over from scratch but retain those folders automagically.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue happens with a domain profile that has backups, the best solution would be to restore the profile from a backup prior to when the issue started.  This is what I had to do for a user who continuously kept getting logged in with a temporary profile.  This also saves time in having to create a new profile and housekeeping to remove the old profile.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are limited to documents, pictures, etc and you know what needs transferred, I agree that backing up the files elsewhere, deleting the profile, then copying them back is the easiest option. To cleanly delete the profile, make sure to use the User Profiles list in System Properties rather than just deleting the folder:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6904099_remove-entire-windows-xp-profile.html

If you are worried about maintaining all of the other goodies like application settings etc, you might have luck using a tool like Windows Easy Transfer or the User State Migration Tool. Not sure if those will bring along the problem, but they're sure to to comprehensive.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4503

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/user-state-migration-tool.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: If maintaining user preferences is desired, I highly recommend [https://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html](ProfWiz) by Forensit. It's built to migrate local profiles to domain, but you could easily use it to duplicate the user to the same domain.